# Material3 theme doesn't work with dark mode turned on

Tags: android, material-ui, darkmode

I'm learning android development and trying to use `Theme.Material3.DayNight`. It successfully themes the buttons and other Views when I'm in light mode but when I switch to dark mode using my android's system all the theming reverts back to normal. The biggest give away is that the button goes from being an oval to a rectangle.
What I find interesting is that `Theme.Material3.Dark` and `Theme.Material3.Light` work just fine. Of course they don't switch when the system switches between dark and light mode, which is why I want to use `Theme.Material3.DayNight`.

Comment: Proper way is to define themes for day and night separately otherwise you will face UI issues. In res->values and values-night specifically for this purpose. You need to adjust UI for both. Generally, small changes are required to give app consistent look in day and night mode. For eg: copy values into values-night and see the affect.

Comment: @tintin thank you very much. This is working and makes sense. I do wonder however, what is the purpose of day night?